# Shell Scripting - Exiting spark-shell session

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sh

I'm trying to write a shell script that will do the following:
1. initiate spark shell
2. run a SQL query
3. exit the spark session
4. execute the remainder of the bash script 
However, I'm having an issue doing the later two parts. The script does not exit the spark session and the echo statement in the last line gets executed in the spark session giving an error.

This is the code I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
   export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
   spark-shell <<- 'EOF'
   spark.sql("SELECT distinct year, months FROM calendar").show(100, false)
   :quit
   EOF 
echo "Testing: Inline session has ended"
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
scala>            spark.sql("SELECT distinct year, months FROM calendar").show(100, false)
+----+------+
|year|months|
+----+------+
|2017|3     |
|2017|8     |
|2017|10    |
|2018|1     |
|2018|3     |
|2017|7     |
|2018|5     |
|2017|12    |
|2017|9     |
|2017|4     |
|2018|7     |
|2018|6     |
|2017|2     |
|2017|11    |
|2017|5     |
|2018|2     |
|2017|6     |
|2017|1     |
|2018|4     |
+----+------+


scala>    :quit
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
   :quit
   ^

scala>    EOF
<console>:24: error: not found: value EOF
          EOF
          ^

scala>

scala>

scala> echo "Testing: Inline session has ended"
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
echo "Testing: Inline session has ended"
     ^

scala> :quit
```

As you can see, it never exits the spark session. Can anyone help me figure this out? I would really appreciate. Many thanks in advance :).

Comment: I see you're using `<<-` but that is only for tabs. Are you sure its a tab and not spaces? and remove the quotes round `'EOF'`